do it acquire hikaricp connection when using repository interface?
spring data redis version: 2.7.18
Defined Repository
public interface MemberCacheRepository extends CrudRepository<MemberPrincipal, Long> {}

refrence link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/reference/repositories/core-concepts.html
Test
I ran the request 1000 times, and was expecting to acquire 0 connection per request.
However, when I monitored it, I checked that 1000 connections were acquired as below.The expected result is 0 connections.
So I wanna ask if you acquire connection even if i use the repository interface.
UPDATE
I confirmed acquiring connection in RedisTemplate class.


How do you think JPA connects to the database?

@M.Deinum "database" is included redis?

@John Williams why were you delete 'spring-data-redis' tag?

JPA doesn't work with Redis, the query you show is from Hibernate and has nothing to do with Redis.

@M.Deinum

I've added a reference link. About concept using Spring Data Repository
The added hibernate is added to explain the fact that it is different from the expected result(2000).


When this way is used, the implementation class 'SimpleKeyValueRepository' is used.

If you aren't using Hibernate but only Redis it wouldnt do anything with HIkari. So you are either providing the wrong information (about Hibernate instead of Redis) or what you provide is at best confusing.

I removed the tag because your issue is with DB connections to an SQL DB not a redis key/value store.

@M.Deinum ok. i agree for your said. so i edited content. how about this? is this clear?

No it isn't and as stated if it is about Redis there is no HIkari needed. So either you aren't using Redis or you are looking at the wrong things.

@M.Deinum Use Hikari if i used the spring data repository, and no Hikari if you used RedisCacheManager. I've debugged it and confirmed that I get the cache into the repository. And I even checked that the redis-cli saves and deletes the cache.

I'm asking why i get a hikari connection when i obviously use redis.

You obviously aren't using Redis else you wouldn't get Hikari, which also means you have configured a database URL etc. in your application.properties. All in all the conclusion is there is too little information in your question to begin answering this.
